# Overwrite property in Maven Without Tokenization

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-resources-plugin

I would like to set a property in Maven, but also read a sensible default when running the application without Maven.

Currently I have a property file which looks like this:

```
baseUrl=${baseUrl}
```

Using the **maven-resources-plugin**, I can then filter this property, and set it to either the default property in the pom, or overwrite it using `-DbaseUrl=` from the command line. So far so good.

However, I want to go a step further and set a sensible default to `baseUrl` in the property file without having to write hacks in code like this (when the code is run without Maven in a Unit Test):

```
 if ("${baseUrl}".equals(baseUrl)){ /* set to default value */ }
```

Even better, I would like this file to be unversioned such that every developer can set their own value. 
(Actually property files should be hierarchical such that developers only overwrite relevant properties and new properties don't break their build. This is an Android project by the way, and I'm running this code in unit tests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to create a static helper:

```
public class PropertyUtils {


    public static Properties getProperties(Context context)  {
        AssetManager assetManager =  context.getResources().getAssets();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            loadProperties(assetManager, "project.properties", properties);
            if (Arrays.asList(assetManager.list("")).contains("local.properties")){
                loadProperties(assetManager, "local.properties", properties);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return properties;
    }

    private static void loadProperties(AssetManager assetManager, String fileName, Properties properties) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open(fileName);
        properties.load(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Where project.properties in assets directory has the following property:

```
baseUrl=${baseUrl}
```

and local.properties in assets:

```
baseUrl=http://192.168.0.1:8080/
```

local.properties is excluded from version control, and overwrites any project.properties. Thus when building in the CI tool, baseUrl is overridden with relevant value, and when running locally (in IntelliJ), the local.properties value will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the property in the POM, in `<properties>`. The set value will be used unless you override it by using the `-D` switch, a profile, etc. In your case this would be:

```
<properties>
    <baseUrl>some_default_url</baseUrl>
</properties>
```

Comment: I am doing this, but the POM properties aren't available when running unit tests (from IntelliJ). Therefore I absolutely need to read the default property from a file . Hence the use of filtering to write a file with the final version.

Comment: But you haven't mentioned this in your question - at all. I suggest you edit it to correspond to your actual problem, which boils down to **`IntelliJ IDEA` not filtering test resources**. otherwise you might not get answers that are useful to you. BTW, I'm not familiar with `IntelliJ`, but I suggest checking if there's some configuration option left unticked, or if it's not a paid-for feature. And one more thing - do you have your `testResources` filtering set up correctly (not the same as `resources`)?